# Suggested books on spatial statistics

Tags: sampling, mathematical-statistics, references, spatial

What are some of the best books for studying 
i) variability of univariate and multivariate variables (real, count data) across a spatial domain.
ii) sampling a univariate or multivariate variable based on its distribution across spatial locations. (Spatial sampling in short)

Comment: what area are you in? I have plenty of references on spatial statistics in ecology... but it might or might not be of use for you,  depends on the area

Comment: Am a statistician-and hence open to all sub-domains and also do a fair amount of machine learning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok. These books seem to be general books on spatial statistics, not restricted to particular area:

1. *[Bivand et al - Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R](http://books.google.cz/books?id=4gg8yx_lcj0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)* - This book was recommended in some presentation at an ecological conference.
2. *[Banerjee et. al - Hierarchical Modeling and Analysis for Spatial Data](http://www.nhbs.com/hierarchical_modeling_and_analysis_for_spatial_data_tefno_179073.html)*. This one I just found randomly I think, don't know nothing about it...

From my perspective of Population Ecology and Species Distribution Modelling, I've come accross these books:

1. *[Janet Franklin - Mapping Species Distributions: Spatial Inference and Prediction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521700027)*.
   I like this book, it seems to be quite nice for beginners.
2. *[Peterson et al - Ecological Niches and Geographic Distributions](http://books.google.cz/books/about/Ecological_Niches_and_Geographic_Distrib.html?id=Q_h9FlvgM6wC&redir_esc=y)*. I haven't read this book but my advisor recommends it as a good piece of work on SDM.
3. *[Rhodes et al - Population Dynamics in Ecological Space and Time](http://books.google.cz/books?id=WGIFt8UQ_l4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Population+Dynamics+in+Ecological+Space+and+Time&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EqYPUY3kH4uO4gS9sICACQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA)*. This one I just found randomly I think, don't know nothing about it.
4. *[Tilman et al - Spatial Ecology: The Role of Space in Population Dynamics and Interspecific Interactions](http://www.nhbs.com/spatial_ecology_tefno_63337.html)*. This one I just found randomly I think, don't know nothing about it.