# Suggested books/readings on spatial statistics for remote sensing

Tags: spatial, image-processing

I'm taking a class on statistics for image analysis and I'm thinking of getting some background reading on the subject. Anybody know a good book/website/readings on the subject? I'm coming from a geomatics background. So far I've found [Spatial Statistics for Remote Sensing](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F0-306-47647-9) but I'd like to have more than one book.

Comment: Related:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49166/suggested-books-on-spatial-statistics   please tell us if that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for the link @kjetilbhalvorsen! However, those focus on geographic information systems and mapping. I need resources for the statistical analysis of remote sensing images.